# Walkable and non Walkable tile map in Corona

Tags: coronasdk

I am able to create a map using Tiled map editor (http://www.mapeditor.org/) and Load it in corona using this library (http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/gridmap). I created a maze map in tiled map editor, but I don't know how to set the wall to be non walkable. Any help, ideas, links would be much appreciated. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

I have done what you are trying to do with gridmap and tiled.

In Tiled, create the non-walkable parts in a separate layer, then right click that layer in the layers palette. Select 'Layer Properties'. Under the name heading, type Physics:existent. Under the value heading, type true. Save and export as a lua file and include in your project and your done!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how Tiled works or how large your map is.. or if your even still having trouble with this. However, recently I was working on an app where I needed an object to collide with walls (in a room/building). What I did was created the image on the entire room (walls and all) in Photoshop. Then I set it as the background and just used rectangles (display.newRect) to create invisible walls that were displayed beneath my room image. You could try something similar if you are still looking for ideas.

for example:

```
wall1 = display.newRect(x, y, w, h)
wall2 = display.newRect(x, y, w, h)
wall3 = display.newRect(x, y, w, h)
wall4 = display.newRect(x, y, w, h)

background = display.newImage("", x, y)

physics.addBody(wall1, "static")
...
...
...
```

In this fasion I was able to map out the walls in the image with actual rectangles and add them to physics so I could collide with them, all the while the user thinks they are colliding with the walls in my image.